# I'd like to know how to compile cutelyst test with cmake finding dependencies

Tags: cmake, compilation, dependencies, lib

I do not know CMake very well. I need for CMake to find the GrantLee library to compile `MyApp` Test in cutelyst Cutelyst Tutorial.
But when I try to compile, I got the  error below.
I have this line in myapp.cpp:

```
#include <Cutelyst/Plugins/View/Grantlee/grantleeview.h>
```

That instance in my code.

```
auto view = new GrantleeView(this);
```

I got that error:

```
Target "MyApp" links to target "Cutelyst::View::Grantlee" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I have that file in my directory:

```
/usr/include/cutelyst2-qt5/Cutelyst/Plugins/View/Grantlee/grantleeview.h
```

How to add this to CMakeLists.txt, for cmake to find dependencies and compile?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is hard to understand what the problem might be without seeing your CMake code. Please add the CMake file you are using to your question post.

Comment: Include the CMake code in your question please. The error is there.